# How Can I Gradually Add More Force To An Object To Increase It's Speed Regardless of It's Direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new in Unity. I am trying to make a 2D game similar to Pong. However, I want to increase more speed to Ball over time to make it harder. I set the gravity scale of the Ball to zero so that it doesn't fall down.
I added a force and bouncy Physics element to the ball. So it bounces back from walls and it goes to different directions.

Here is a screenshot of Game I'm working on:
[image]

MY QUESTION IS:

- How can I add more force to the ball regardless of which direction it
  bounces back?

<Note: I tried putting it inside FixedUpdate () method but the ball goes crazy because of constantly executing same function every frame. I was thinking of adding more force to the ball over time by using InvokeRepeating ( ) method later on to set time interval. If there is better idea of using other techniques, giving me a little advice will help me a lot>
Thank you !

Comment: Please do not use screenshots to include code in questions. Use text instead. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please use the correct tags. Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code rather looks like `c#`. Also as already mentioned before [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) or an [InvokeRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html). I would also recommend changing your code a bit.

`rbBall.AddForce(rbBall.transform.right * ballForce)`

The above snippet will add the `ballForce` in the direction the `rbBall` is moving.

Now for the two example snippets.

**Coroutine**

```
private float timeBeforeAddForce = 5f;

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(GradualAddForceToBall());
}

private IEnumerator GradualAddForceToBall()
{
    // wait for 5 seconds
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBeforeAddForce);
    
    // add the speed
    rbBall.AddForce(rbBall.transform.right * ballForce)
    
    // call the coroutine again
    StartCoroutine(GradualAddForceToBall());
}
```

**InvokeRepeating**

```
private void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("GradualAddForceToBall", 0.0f, timeBeforeAddForce);
}

private void GradualAddForceToBall()
{
     rbBall.AddForce(rbBall.transform.right * ballForce)
}
```

If you want to change the current time of how long the speed is applied, I would go with the `Coroutine` as you can gradually decrease the `timeBeforeAddingForce` every time it enters the `Coroutine`.

Comment: It works. I found another solution which is using normalized value. Here's the code:   public float currentSpeed = 5f;
void FixedUpdate()
{
    //This will let you adjust the speed of ball using normalization
    rbBall.velocity = rbBall.velocity.normalized * currentSpeed;
}

Comment: Yes that is just getting the current velocity as a direction vector removing all magnitude. It is a constant velocity not a force. It is different.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. You can force an object to be a specific speed while keeping its same movement direction - normalize the velocity (which sets the value to have a mangitude of 1) and then multiply it by your desired speed:

**Here is the code:**

```
public float currentSpeed = 5f;
void FixedUpdate()
{
    //This will let you adjust the speed of ball using normalization
    rbBall.velocity = rbBall.velocity.normalized * currentSpeed;
}
```

Adjust the currentSpeed variable to change it's speed.
""